# The Art of Electronics (Integrators)

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrator

Reading this topic from "The Art of Electronics" : [Integrators](https://archive.org/details/TheArtOfElectronics-2ndEdition/page/n37)

How does RC keep V << Vin?

[image]

Comment: It is not a matter of RC keeping ("forcing") V << Vin. You should interpret this as: RC should be large, then when V << Vin we can use the formula. If RC is small and/or V isn't much smaller than Vin, we cannot use the formula.

Comment: It doesn't say RC keeps V << Vin. It says "we" keep it this way.

Comment: For those without access to the text the OP refers to, the fuller context can be read [here at the end of page 26 of the older 2nd edition](https://archive.org/details/TheArtOfElectronics-2ndEdition/page/n37).

Comment: To the OP: All that's being said here is that if you can arrange things so that the capacitor stays relatively uncharged, then the charging current will closely approximate a constant. If, on the other hand, you allow the capacitor to charge "for a long enough while" then the magnitude of the current will be seen to change over time and can't be considered a constant, anymore. In that case, you wind up with no longer a constant but instead a continually varying current and, ultimately, it involves exponentials/logarithms and stuff gets more complicated.

Comment: To the OP.  This was not explained well at all in the book.  I can see why you are confused.  Because the author did a shit job of explaining it.  He also does a shit job of explaining what he meant in section 1.4.3 Differentiators by saying to "keep dVout/dt << dVin/dt."  Nobody is going to look at the math and understand that, especially without deeper understanding of RC circuits.  Overall, the author failed the reader in those sections.

Comment: When the author explained the integrator circuit, he should have converted the source and showed it as a norton equivalent circuit because that's what he was aiming for: a constant current source.  The results would have been a current source in parallel with a high impedance charging a parallel capacitor. I honestly thought he did a terrible job in those sections.

Answer (score 1):

If \$RC\$ is very large, current is very small,  \$\frac{dV}{dt}\$ goes to zero, thus \$V\$ does not change.

Comment: @Scott Seidman I don't understand what you're saying here.  Why do we want dV/dt to go to zero?  We want dV/dt to form a ramp.  In order to form a ramp, we inject a constant current into a capacitor.  When we inject a constant current into a capacitor, Vc(t) changes very slowly in the form of a ramp.  The idea is to only take the starting linear part of the exponential RC curve.  He explains the basic idea like garbage.  The only saving grace is Figure 1.47 which shows what he was trying to explain.

Comment: There are actually two ways to interpret this and what he was trying to explain.  You can view it from the perspective of voltage or current in the circuit.  He needed to explain it both ways for the section to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

If RC is large, then V will grow more slowly than it would if RC was small. So over the course of the integration, V will stay smaller, making it easier to keep V much less than Vin. It's a rather dense sentence, and it's easy to get confused in it.